# Possible to use :before pseudo-selector on itself?

Tags: css

For example, something like:

**HTML**

```
<p>text</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p:before {
content: " 1";
}

p:before:before {
content: " 2";
}
```

Which would end up with something like this:

```
text 1 2
```

---

If this isn't possible, is there any way to emulate the same effect?

In my project I have the original text content hidden with `font-size:0` and added coloured text in it's place with the `:before` pseudo-selector.

However, it's 2 words, so I'd like to be able to add more content AFTER the generated content to change the colour.

[image]

The "GLB Guide" is generated using `:before`, but I'd like to be able to make both words different colours.

Hope that made sense!

Comment: The only thing is that there is :after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like following which make you text with two different color:

```css
p:before {
content: " GLB";
color: red;
}

p:after {
content: " Guide";
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked marvelously! It never crossed my mind that you could use :before and :after on the same element.